# How to draw a set of horizontal lines?

Tags: java, opengl, processing, lines

I am new to OpenGL as learning exercise I decided to draw a set of horizontal lines from a grid of m x n matrix containing the vertices locations

This is what I have
[image]

and If I use LINE_STRIP
[image]

**A code snippet using vertex arrays and indices will be great, I cant seem to be able to get the concept just from a text book I need to see and play with a code example
Any help will be much appreciated!**

---

@Thomas
Got it working with the following code

```
totalPoints = GRID_ROWS * 2 * (GRID_COLUMNS - 1);
indices = new int[totalPoints];

points = new GLModel(this, totalPoints, LINES, GLModel.DYNAMIC);
int n = 0;
points.beginUpdateVertices();
for ( int row = 0; row < GRID_ROWS; row++ ) {
  for ( int col = 0; col < GRID_COLUMNS - 1; col++ ) {
    int rowoffset = row * GRID_COLUMNS;
    int n0 = rowoffset + col;
    int n1 = rowoffset + col + 1;

    points.updateVertex( n, pointsPos[n0].x, pointsPos[n0].y, pointsPos[n0].z );
    indices[n] = n0;
    n++;

    points.updateVertex( n, pointsPos[n1].x, pointsPos[n1].y, pointsPos[n1].z );
    indices[n] = n1;
    n++;
  }
}
points.endUpdateVertices();
```

Then I update and draw by doing

```
points.beginUpdateVertices();
for ( int n = 0; n < totalPoints; n++ ) {
   points.updateVertex( n, pointsPos[indices[n]].x, pointsPos[indices[n]].y, pointsPos[indices[n]].z );
}
points.endUpdateVertices();
```

This is the result

[image]

---

Fix it by changing the nested for loop

```
for ( int col = 0; col < GRID_COLUMNS; col++ ) {
for ( int row = 0; row < GRID_ROWS - 1; row++ ) {
    int offset = col * GRID_ROWS;
    int n0 = offset + row;
    int n1 = offset + row + 1;
    indices[n++] = n0;
    indices[n++] = n1;
  }
}
```

Now I can have any number of rows and columns

Thanks agin!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to draw a line for each segment and resuse an index, i.e. for the first part you'd draw a line for (0,1), (1,2), (2,3) and so on.

Edit:

Suppose you have a 4x5 array (4 lines, 5 vertices per line). You could then calculate the indices like this (pseudo code):

```
Vertex[] v = new Vertex[20]; // 20 vertices in the grid
for(int row = 0; row < numrows; row++) // numrows = 4
{
  int rowoffset = row * numcols ; //0, 4, 8, 12
  for(int col = 0; col < (numcols - 1); col++) //numcols = 5
  {
     addLineIndices(rowoffset + col, rowoffset + col +1); //adds (0,1), (1,2), (2,3) and (3, 4) for the first row
  }
}
```

Then issue the draw call for `numrows * (numcols - 1)` linesegments (GL_LINES), i.e. 16 in the example. Note that `addLineIndices` would be a function that adds the index pair for one line segment to an index array which is then supplied to the draw call.

Comment: Thanks a lot working like a charm, but it works for a n x n grid it does not work with m x n so if the number of rows is different than the number of columns the drawing gets messy, any ideas?

Comment: This should work for n x m, too. If numcols would be 5, for example, rowoffset should be 0, 5, 10, 15. I'd suspect you got something wrong in your calculation or your vertex array. Could add some code to your question?